# Using Enumeration for shared variables in Scala

Tags: scala

*Is it the right pattern to use Enumeration for holding shared variable values?*

I am accepting arguments from the command line - arguments like "mongoUsername", "mongoPassword", "mongoDatabase" etc. - across a lot of different files, and want to remove the possibility of making a mistake while specifying the argument name.

I created an object as follows:

```
object CommonParams extends Enumeration {
  val MONGO_USERNAME = "mongoUsername"
  val MONGO_PASSWORD = "mongoPassword"
  ..
}
```

When accepting these parameters from the command line, the parameters will be read using CommonParams.MONGO_USERNAME rather than just "mongoUsername". This method works. My question is:

- Is this the right way to do what I am trying to do?
- I dont think I am using Enumeration correctly. What should I change?
- What would I gain by declaring the CommonParams as follows:

.

```
object CommonParams extends Enumeration {
  val MONGO_USERNAME = Value("mongoUsername")
  val MONGO_PASSWORD = Value("mongoPassword")
  ..
}
```

If I declared CommonParams this way, I would have to use CommonParams.MONGO_USERNAME.toString each time instead of just using CommonParams.MONGO_USERNAME which is more verbose.

I understand that Enumeration can stand for a certain value being a "thing". However, I am holding a value inside an object attribute. What advantages would I get if I used the second way of declaring CommonParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first version, you should remove `extends Enumeration`, since you aren't actually using it.

The benefit of the second version is exactly that `CommonParams.Value`s aren't strings, so that if you have e.g. a method accepting `CommonParams.Value`, you can't accidentally pass an invalid string. And also that you can get methods like `CommonParams.values` to list all values.